# How can I query JSON of an XML parsing in a client only app?

Tags: json, xml, json-query, tei

Sorry for the inappropriate question. But what do you recommend me to use to structure a library that can put a query arrangement on json formats generated by an XML parsing based on TEI p5? I tried to use GraphQL by converting the interfaces of my Angular application related to parsing information from XML to JSON in type to define a GraphQL schema but I don't think that's the way.

What I have to do is query, client only, some data encoded in XML (also wanting already parsed in JSON) and, for example, search for all occurrences of a specific data.

Do you have any roadmaps to recommend or some JSON query system that might be right for me?

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/saxon-js. With SaxonJS you're able to run XPath expression against XML using JavaScript.